# Sonar + Clover only runs on src-instrumented

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, clover

Currently I'm trying to do a Integration Test + Clover +Sonar I was available to do so (I can see in sonar the total coverage,(IT + Unit testing) together ) 
The issue is pretty much that the source been upload to sonar are the ones clover generates to do his thing.

```
[INFO] [16:16:57.566] Working dir:/Users/cortiz/dev/company/tmp/profile/server/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:16:57.566] Source dirs:/Users/cortiz/dev/company/tmp/profile/server/target/clover/src-instrumented
[INFO] [16:16:57.566] Test dirs:/Users/cortiz/dev/company/tmp/profile/server/target/clover/src-test-instrumented
[INFO] [16:16:57.566] Binary dirs:/Users/cortiz/dev/company/tmp/profile/server/target/classes
```

Or a lot __CLR** stuff all around) so the source code is not actually readable or accurate

How I run it is using this command

```
mvn clean clover2:setup install clover2:clover sonar:sonar -PSonar
```

And the Sonar profile is

```
    <profile>
        <id>Sonar</id>
        <properties>
            <clover.version>3.1.8</clover.version>
            <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>clover</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
            <sonar.clover.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/clover.xml</sonar.clover.reportPath>
            <sonar.sources>bork</sonar.sources>
            <sonar.exclusions>**/clover/src-instrumented/**</sonar.exclusions>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${clover.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <license>${clover.license}</license>
                        <reportDescriptor>clover-report.xml</reportDescriptor>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

If needed I can put more info.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your issue? Do you point to the right source code in your maven pom because "sonar.sources" is not taken into account with Maven. Also, you should run mvn sonar:sonar separately. First: mvn clean clover2:setup install clover2:clover, then: mvn sonar:sonar -PSonar

Comment: Hi.
@DavidRACODON
sonar.sources it seams not to be honor (Bug) or at least in this case
stuff look like this. http://cl.ly/image/2f392c0H2C1I
I do follow you advice and solve the issue
   mvn clean clover2:setup install clover2:clover -PSonar
   mvn sonar:sonar -DskipTests -PSonar
Thx

Comment: Nice! Regarding the "sonar.sources" property not taken into account while running the analysis with Maven, it is the expected behavior. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-ProjectConfiguration. This behavior will eventually change: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested by DavidRACODON

```
mvn clean clover2:setup install clover2:clover -PSonar 
mvn sonar:sonar -DskipTests -PSonar
```